# Can't remove outdoor security light fixture

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, outdoor, security

first time poster and home improvement newbie here, please be gentle.
My husband and I are trying to replace a broken outdoor security light that was installed by the previous owner. My husband managed to get all the caulk off and can rotate the fixture in either direction, but it won't come off the wall more than an inch or two, which isn't far enough for him to get behind it to see what is holding it on there. He has removed the only bolt on the front of the fixture, and we can't find any caps or covers that might be hiding more. We have no idea how to remove this thing at this point. Any advice is welcome.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hhow about taking a picture or two so we can see what you see.

Comment: Yes, pic please. And don't forget that security lights are often perpetually hot, so flip the breaker. (Or the whole house if you don't know which one is which.)

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate Absolutely! Always a good thing to remind people! Both my husband and I had bad encounters with electricity as kids, so no worries there.

Comment: @JACK [Image 1](https://imgur.com/YzIjDvV) Best I can do ATM. I have no idea what the right terminology is here, but we think the round metal cylinder part is caulked to the rest of the light, and have no idea how to remedy it.

Comment: @JACK [Another Image](https://imgur.com/gaNPQhT) Sorry, when we went to take the pictures, we disturbed a yellowjacket nest, so this as close as we can get ATM.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate Sorry for the delay had to wait until sunset to deal with the yellowjackets. We have dismantled it as much as possible, still won't come off. Can't find any hidden screws. [Dismantled security light](https://imgur.com/undefined). Aside from just yanking it off (which doesn't seem like a good idea) we are stuck.

Comment: Last pic didn't link properly, but keeping in mind that you're not trying to re-use the unit, a bit of force might be okay. Try to stabilize the junction box while twisting the unit hard anti-clockwise. After that, maybe start breaking things.

Comment: What's the hole in the front above the motion sensor, could it be a screw under a plastic cap? Or, is there a screw on top, on the round part between the lights? Or a set screw somewhere around the perimeter of the round base plate?  This thing looks a little homegrown. Maybe it's glued together.

Comment: [video](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/OrIY8xI1MCU) Hopefully that link works. It appears the pieces are caulked or epoxied together in such a way that we can't separate them. We are worried that if we cut the wires we won't have enough wire to attach the new light.

Comment: SUCCESS!!!! We managed to get a knife in the gap and cut the cursed thing out.

Answer (score 5):

The light was EPOXIED into its housing (please don't ever do this) and took some serious prying to get out. Use caulk if you use anything!

Comment: Yeah, someone decided to make the installation rather *too* permanent from the sounds of things!

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a Defiant unit, and there could be plastic caps over the screws as pictured. If not, comment back and I'll delete.

[image]

It may also be an earlier version, in which case you might try twisting and pulling, on the notion that there's a sub-base that's actually screwed to the junction box.

Comment: This definitely qualifies as *an* answer. It may or may not be correct for the OP, but it’s an answer.